# How to detect event on text box field in blackberry?

Tags: blackberry

I want to add one text field on my screen.when i enter any word/letter in that text box i want to know what word/letter I had entered.i also want to handle event on occurence of any new letter entered in that text box or after deletion of any word/letter from that text box.so how should be it handled?

Comment: Why dont u use KeywordFilterField.Read this [link](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/11958/Create_a_search_field_508886_11.jsp)

Comment: There are some limitations to use that KeywordFilterField because it requires readable list as input while i want to give Vector as input thats why i am not using that please tell me about text field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just implement and set `FieldChangeListener` for this field